# How to force a select box's elements to open downwards on CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a select box that opens upwards instead of downwards.

When I open it, it opens upwards because there is not enough space to open all of the options downwards, How can I do so it will open downwards, and when the space is over I'll just need to scroll to see the rest?

Here is all of the code thats related to the select box:

```css
.select-box {
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
}
    
.select-box::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: white;
}
    
.select-box::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 5px);
    right: 10px;
    border: solid black;
    border-width: 0 1.5px 1.5px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    pointer-events: none;
}
    
.select-box select[open="down"] {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: auto;
}
    
.select-box select[open="down"]::after {
    top: calc(50% - 5px);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <select id="day" name="day" autocomplete="off" required class="select-box">
    <!-- Header (null value) -->
    <option value="">Day</option>

    <!-- Options -->
    <!-- On my code echo by PHP -->
    <?php
      for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++) {
        echo "<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>";
      }
    ?>
    <!-- On snippet echo manually -->
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="26">26</option>
    <option value="27">27</option>
    <option value="28">28</option>
    <option value="29">29</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="31">31</option>
  </select>
</div>
```